# Mock object is null in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

I'm writing a unit test and i have 1 mock object that will return a dynamic type which has JSON in it. The call is async and looks to be fine, however when i run the code and step into class im testing, the mock is null (m.GetResults) and the return data i set isnt shown.

Im new to using Moq and not sure if I've done something wrong. Can anyone spot any issue for why it would be null?

```
public async Task GetPaymentDetailSummaryTestAsync(){                        

    Task<dynamic> json = GetSampleJsonAsync();

    var mock = new Mock<ICallProcedure>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.GetResults("dbo.GetPaymentDetailSummary", 
                                 new { ID = 600002, Year = 2018})) 
                                .ReturnsAsync(json);            

    var payments = new Payments(mock.Object);
    var result = await payments.GetPaymentDetailSummaryAsync(2018, 600002);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(List<PaymentSummary>));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
}

public async Task<dynamic> GetSampleJsonAsync(){            
    return await Task.FromResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("[{\"PaymentNumber\":1,\"Payment\":1200.00}]")); 
}
```

`Payments` class under test

```
public class Payments : IPayments
{
    private ICallProcedure callProc;

    public Payments(ICallProcedure CallProc)
    {
        callProc = CallProc;
    }

    public async Task<List<PaymentSummary>> GetPaymentDetailSummaryAsync(int year, int iD)
    {
        var getPaymentDetailSummary = await callProc.GetResults("dbo.GetPayment", new { ID = id, Year = year });
        List<PaymentSummary> paymentDetailSummary = null;
        paymentDetailSummary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentSummary>>(getPaymentDetailSummary);

        return paymentDetailSummary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `GetPaymentDetailSummaryAsync` method? Are you getting `m` as null or `m.GetResults` returns null?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've found out the issue. I put this line in: mock.Setup(m => m.GetResults(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())).ReturnsAsync(json); .......... However my issue now is to do with the return being a task instead of the result. The following line tries to deserialize a task instead of the result which would be json. I dont wana change the code in the class just the unit test: paymentDetailSummary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentSummary>>(getPaymentDetailSummary);

Answer (score 1):

You have already figured out that the setup of the mock was not matching the actual behavior to the expected behavior and that using the `It.IsAny<T>()` was the solution for that problem like

```
mock.Setup(_ => _.GetResults(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())) 
    .ReturnsAsync(json);
```

The resulting problem, based on the class under test and the set up of the mock is that it appears you are double serializing the expected JSON result. You manually create a JSON string and then serialize that again.

Consider refactoring the test to something a little simpler that generates the JSON using an actual object instead of try to craft it manually. The same object can be used for making assertions as well.

```
public async Task GetPaymentDetailSummaryTestAsync(){                        
    //Arrange
    List<PaymentSummary> expected = new List<PaymentSummary> {
        new PaymentSummary {
            PaymentNumber = 1,
            Payment = 1200.00
        }
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expected);

    var mock = new Mock<ICallProcedure>();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.GetResults(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())) 
        .ReturnsAsync(json);            

    var payments = new Payments(mock.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = await payments.GetPaymentDetailSummaryAsync(2018, 600002);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(List<PaymentSummary>));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count);
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
}
```